# Proof regarding countable sets and sequences

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

> Let $A$ be a set of infinite sequences of natural numbers, such that
> every two sequences in $A$ are identical as of a certain point. Prove
> that $A$ is countable.

I was given this question and tried solving it, but I have a feeling that my solution is very abstract and I'm not sure about it.. especially the definitions of the set S and the function.. how can I improve it/make it clearer?

Let $i∈N$. Let $S_{i}⊆A$, $S_{i} = \text{The set of all sequences in $A$ that are identical from index $i$.}$

We show there exists a function $f:\ S_{i\ }\to N^{i}$ that is total and injective.

Let $f:\ S_{i\ }\to N^{i}$, $f(x) = \text{A sequence of the first $i$ elements of sequence $x$}$.

$f$ is total:

Let $s∈S_{i}$. As $s$ is a sequence of natural numbers, and by definition of $f$, $f(s)$ is a sequence of length $i$, $f(s)∈N^{i}$.

$f$ is injective:

Let $s_{1}$,$s_{2}∈S_{i}$. Assume $f(s_{1})=f(s_{2})$. Then by the definition of $f$ and sequence equality $s_{1}$,$s_{2}$ are identical up to index $i$. By defintion of $S_{i}$, $s_{1}$,$s_{2}$ are identical starting from index $i$. Therefore $s_{1}=s_{2}$.

As $f$ is total and injective, $\left|S_{i\ }\right|\le\left|N^{i}\right|$. As $\left|N^{i}\right|=\left|N\right|=א_{0}$, $S_{i}\leא_{0}$.

Therefore $S_{i}$ is countable. As $\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty S_n = A$ and $S_{n}\leא_{0}$ for every $i∈N$, by countable union $|A|≤א_{0}$.

Comment: I take it "total" means surjective or onto and that $N^i$ is the set of all finite sequences of length $i$?

Comment: SOmetimes instead of going $S \to N$ in steps it's easier to go from $N \to S$ in steps.

Comment: The definition of $S_i$ makes no sense: what does it mean to say that _a_ sequence is "identical starting from index $i$"? Identical to what?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I don't quiet get what you mean. I was trying to copy the conditions in the question itself..

Comment: It's curious that you say you don't get what I mean, when what I meant was I don't understand what you mean by a certain phrase. Say $s$ is a sequence. What does it mean to say "$s$ is identical starting from index $i=3$"? Can you give an example and another example of a sequence that is _not_ "identical starting from index $i=3$"?

Comment: (Hint: regardless of what you were trying to do, what you actually did was copy the _words_, not the "conditions"...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix some $a=(a_j)_j\in A.$ For $i\in \Bbb N$ and for $b=(b_j)_j\in A$, let $b\in F(i)$ if $\forall j>i\,(b_j=a_j).$ Each $F(i)$ is countable and $A=\cup_{i\in\Bbb N}F(i).$

Remark:  $F(i), F(i')$ are not disjoint when $i\ne i'$ because $a$ belongs to every $F(i)$, but it does not matter.